# Create a Parent with existing children in EntityFramework core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am building a Web API and have two models: Task and Feature:

```
public class Feature
{
    [Key]
    public long FeatureId { get; set; }
    public string Analyst_comment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User_Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public Feature()
    {

    }
}

public class User_Task
{
    [Key]
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    public string What { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FeatureId")]
    public long? FeatureId { get; set; }


    public User_Task()
    {

    }

}
```

I create Tasks first and then create a Feature that combines few of them. Task creation is successful, however while creating a Feature with existing Tasks, my controller throws an error saying the task already exists:

My FeatureController has following method:

```
//Create
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Feature item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    ** It basically expects that I am creating a Feature with brand new tasks, so I guess I will need some logic here to tell EF Core that incoming tasks with this feature already exist **

    _featureRepository.Add(item);

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetFeature", new { id = item.FeatureId }, item);
}
```

How to tell EF core that incoming Feature has Tasks that already exist and it just needs to update the references instead of creating new ones?

My context:

```
public class WebAPIDataContext : DbContext
{
    public WebAPIDataContext(DbContextOptions<WebAPIDataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User_Task> User_Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Feature> Features { get; set; }

}
```

And repo:

```
public void Add(Feature item)
{
    _context.Features.Add(item);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Did you try attaching it already? Dunno how you repository implementation is and what it returns, so you may to do the attachments inside the repository (in an AddOrUpdate method?). `context.Attach(item)` should attach a detached item. The reason is, that EF Core tracks items based on the changetracker. When an item is not in the tracker and you call ".Add" it will treat it as insert. When you attach it, it will look if the entity exists and if yes, will load it into the tracker and then track the changes and perform update

Comment: I have updated my question with context and repo class  method. Perhaps now could you point out exactly what could I do?

Comment: Does `_context.Attach(item)` before (or instead of) `context.Features.Add(item)` solve it?

Comment: Also see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud#update-the-edit-page) for examples and recommended usage of ASP.NET Core + EF Core

Comment: Putting it before Add() gives Arithmetic exception, putting it after Add() also throws an exception. When I used instead of Add(), there is no error and I got a response (got feature with featureId=0) but nothing was created in database

Answer (score 0):

When calling Add on a DBSet with a model that was not loaded from EF, it thinks it is untracked and will always assume it is new.

Instead, you need to load the existing record from the dbcontext and map the properties from the data passed into the API to the existing record. Typically that is a manual map from parameter object to domain. Then if you return an object back, you would map that new domain object to a DTO. You can use services like AutoMapper to map the domain to a DTO. When you're done mapping, you only need to call SaveChanges.

Generally speaking, loading the record and mapping the fields is a good thing for the security of your API. You wouldn't want to assume that the passed in data is pristine and honest. When you give the calling code access to all the properties of the entity, you may not be expecting them to change all the fields, and some of those fields could be sensitive.

Comment: No-no! Don't use Automapper to map from DTOs back to Persistence Objects (DAOs)! Only from DAO -> DTO or Domain -> DTO/ViewModel. Never the other way around. AutoMapper was not designed for this and it won't work in most non-trivial cases, see [this](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/), it will **never** end up well and cause more trouble then it saves

Comment: Calm down... that wasn't the intent. I'll edit the answer to clarify that.