# entity framework core add new entity with related entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a Net Core 3.1 MVC project where a `Playlist` can be created and added to an existing `Team`. I run in to problems when I try to save the `Playlist` entity with `_context.Add(playlist)` and then _context.SaveChangesAsync() with the following error:

```
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Teams' with unique index 'IX_Teams_TeamName'. The duplicate key value is (Team Name Four).
The statement has been terminated.
```

My code:

```
PlaylistDTO dto = new PlaylistDTO();
dto.Name = "new playlist with related team";
dto.Team = _context.Team.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id) // id comes from viewmodel
Playlist storeToDb = _mapper.Map<Playlist>(dto)
_context.Playlists.Add(storeToDb);
                    
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // throws error cannot insert duplicates.
```

My entities:

```
public class Playlist: AuditEntity
{
    // id comes from AuditEntity
    public string PlayListName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class Team: AuditEntity
{
    // id comes from AuditEntity
    public string TeamName {get; set; }
    // other properties, including other related entities
    public ICollection<Playlist> Playlists {get; set;}
}
```

My DbConfig file

```
public class TeamDbConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Team>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Team> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Teams");

        builder.HasIndex(t => t.TeamName)
            .IsUnique();

        // one2many rel for playlist. One team can have multiple playlists
        builder.HasMany(t => t.Playlists)
            .WithOne(pl => pl.Team)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            
    }
}
```

In a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198772/create-a-parent-with-existing-children-in-entityframework-core) it was explained that with .Add() EF will treat any objects as new (and so it cannot add an entity with restricted columns twice). However, I don't know how to get this to work. Loading it untracked vs tracked, setting the Entry().EntityState to Modified or Unchanged doesn't seem to do anything.

This seems to be a pretty standard thing to do, yet I cannot get it done. So, I have a few questions:

- Given what I want (a user can add an existing team to a new playlist), do I have the correct relationships defined between Team and Playlist?
- What do I need to use as a statement instead (or in addition to) the Add() statement that I now have?

Comment: Can you post the real code pls? It is vital if you want to get help. You have posted _context.Playlists.Add(storeToDb); but storeToDb is not even defined.

Comment: The error is not about id by the way, error says unique index (Name column) is violated. And where you configure primary key (Id column?) for your Team entity?

Comment: What happens in `_mapper.Map<Playlist>(dto)`? It seems that there a new `Team` object is created.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using net 3.1 you have to add TeamId to

```
public class Playlist: AuditEntity
{
    // id comes from AuditEntity
    public string PlayListName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

     public int? TeamId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(TeamId))]
    [InverseProperty("Playlists")]
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class Team: AuditEntity
{
    // id comes from AuditEntity
    public string TeamName {get; set; }
    // other properties, including other related entities

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Playlist.Team))]
    public ICollection<Playlist> Playlists {get; set;}
}

[InverseProperty(nameof(FirstClass.SecondClass))]


modelBuilder.Entity<PlayList>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Team)
                   .WithMany(p => p.Playlists)
                   .HasForeignKey(d => d.TeamId);
            });
```

and use it to assign to playlist

```
PlaylistDTO dto = new PlaylistDTO();
dto.Name = "new playlist with related team";
dto.TeamId=id;  // id comes from viewmodel

Playlist storeToDb = _mapper.Map<Playlist>(dto)
_context.Playlists.Add(storeToDb);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```